# Cinema 4D - Import xlwt location

Tags: python, macos, xlwt, cinema-4d

I'm trying to read excel from Cinema4d using python. I believed this can be achieved using **`XLWT`**. Where did I should copy and pasthe the **`XLWT`** package in **Mac**? I know in **Window** the location is here :`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MAXON\CINEMA 4D version\library\python\packages\`. How about Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the python packages into the Python Library Folder of Cinema4D. If you select the Preferences Menu in Cinema4D there is a Button called "Open Preferences Folder..." this will lead to a folder called CINEMA 4D R_ 
Inside this folder library/python/packages/osx/ is the folder where you have to install the xlrd and xlwt packages. 
If this is successful you should be able to access Excel files...

Answer (score 0):

Since Python is already on OS X you should be able to use:

```
easy_install xlwt
```

or

```
pip install xlwt
```

If you download xlwt then you could use:

```
python setup.py install
```